# Error reading data in Firestore with Nuxt Js using Fetch Hook

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I was trying to do pagination with firebase and nuxt js . When trying to read from firestore using the fetch hook I get an error (Maximum call stack size exceeded ). It is worth noting that when doing this same process with the hook mounted works perfectly. I need to use the fetch hook for ssr. I think the error comes from assigning the value to the variable lastDoc which I need to save the cursor that I will later use in the pagination.

Here is the code

```
async fetch() {
let queryShows = query(
  collection(db, "shows"),
  orderBy("ano", "desc"),
  orderBy("nombre", "asc"),
  limit(3)
);
const querySnapshotShows = await getDocs(queryShows);
this.lastDoc = querySnapshotShows.docs[querySnapshotShows.docs.length - 1]; //Don't know why this cause an error
querySnapshotShows.forEach((doc) => {
  this.shows.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
});}
```

Here is the error
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJiMG.jpg)

Comment: Please i need help

Comment: Maybe this will help -> https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6294#issuecomment-749343260

Comment: Maybe this will help -> github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6294#issuecomment-749343260